# Injecting PolyFill into a React Component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

So I hear using jQuery is an anti-pattern in react.  So how then are people injecting things like polyfills?

For example here for Object.assign(), [Mozilla provides a very simple polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill) script that I'd like to try out. *(yes I know there are things like babel-polyfill, etc. I just want to try injection js period, I don't need to get fancy here yet)*

I assume you'd inject this in the componentDidMount().  But if not using jQuery are people simply using plain JS and the document object?

Comment: I'm curious, how does jQuery help with including polyfills? That polyfill from mozilla could just be copied into your app, for instance in a script tag above the rest of your code and `Object` would have an assign method.

Comment: it depends, sometimes it's a timing thing and you need to load it after a component mounts.  Maybe in this case you can just require it.  I tried that but I'll try it again, I didn't have luck that route

Comment: You shouldn't need to require anything, polyfills are global things.. just add that code in your index.html above your bundle file

Comment: yea realized that now, I'm using babel-polyfill

Comment: I was just trying to figure out how to render it via my top level react component is all.  I had to just enable it in gulp really, that's where I setup the polyfill.